# querydsl exists duplicate condition

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

here is my full sql as

```
new BooleanBuilder(
    qClaimDataEntity.companyId.eq(companyId)           
        .or(
            qClaimDataEntity.projectDataEntity.remoteProjectDataEntityList
            .any().assignedCompanyId.eq(companyId)
        )
        .or(
            qClaimDataEntity.projectDataEntity.remoteProjectDataEntityList
            .any().remoteProjectStatus.eq(RemoteProjectStatusEnum.合作中)
        )
    );
```

it print sql string as

```
select
    claimdatae0_.*
from
    claim_data claimdatae0_ 
where
    claimdatae0_.company_id=? 
    or exists (
        select
            1 
        from
            project_data projectdat1_ cross 
        join
            remote_project_data remoteproj2_ 
        where
            claimdatae0_.project_data_id=projectdat1_.project_data_id 
            and projectdat1_.project_data_id=remoteproj2_.project_data_id 
            and remoteproj2_.assigned_company_id=?
    ) 
    or exists (
        select
            1 
        from
            project_data projectdat3_ cross 
        join
            remote_project_data remoteproj4_ 
        where
            claimdatae0_.project_data_id=projectdat3_.project_data_id 
            and projectdat3_.project_data_id=remoteproj4_.project_data_id 
            and remoteproj4_.remote_project_status=?
    ) limit ?
```

but I think it can be done as

```
select
    claimdatae0_.* 
from
    claim_data claimdatae0_ 
where
    claimdatae0_.company_id=? 
    or exists (
        select
            1 
        from
            project_data projectdat1_ cross 
        join
            remote_project_data remoteproj2_ 
        where
            claimdatae0_.project_data_id=projectdat1_.project_data_id 
            and projectdat1_.project_data_id=remoteproj2_.project_data_id 
            and remoteproj2_.assigned_company_id=?
            and remoteproj2_.remote_project_status=?
    ) limit ?
```

SubQuery is not support in latest Spring data jpa
and querydsl .any() don't support duplicate condition
is there another way to get the second query using querydsl?

Comment: Why do you think the second query would be better than the first? Have you looked at the execution plan or have you measured performance?

Answer (score 0):

The example is two separate `or` statements. I think the `or` should be nested, like this:

```
        new BooleanBuilder(
            qClaimDataEntity.companyId.eq(companyId)
                    .or(
                            qClaimDataEntity.projectDataEntity.remoteProjectDataEntityList
                                    .any().assignedCompanyId.eq(companyId)
                                    .or(
                                            qClaimDataEntity.projectDataEntity.remoteProjectDataEntityList
                                                    .any().remoteProjectStatus.eq(RemoteProjectStatusEnum.合作中)
                                    )
                    ));
```